# Shall I create a Superclass I will never instance just for casting different subclasses?

Tags: java, casting, superclass

I just started learning Java and I have this question. Lets say I have classes A and B. I need a variable which could be an object type A or type B. I believe that creating a new Superclass P for A and B will make it. But I will never create an instance of P, I will allways use type A or B objects.

I thought that maybe using an abstract class for P would make more sense, since no instances of it will be ever made, but then I cannot cast A or B to it. Then, is this the only way and the right way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If `A` and `B` extend abstract class `P`, you can cast them to `P`. This code is perfectly valid: `P parent =  new A();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rule of thumb is to create an interface.

If the two classes really share common behaviour, it might be that you actually can use an abstract superclass to have the common implementation in this superclass.

Though be cautious with creating such a superclass as often superclasses are created based on laziness and not due to real common relation between classes.

With having either an interface or a superclass, statements like the following is always true

`P object = new A();`
`P object2 = new B();`

Comment: Let's suppose I also want A and B to have a variable in common, so then I could do `int a = object.var` no matter if _object_ is A or B type. Should I use a superClass?

Comment: Don't do this (public fields), you would be exposing internal implementation details which is rarely a good idea.
Ask yourself: Do you need that `a` value somewhere else? In that case, maybe it's stored in the wrong class? Or maybe the method that needs it should be in the `P` superclass instead?

Comment: public fields are ok for immutable final fields - but thats another discussion ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You should create an [*interface*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html), not a superclass.